# Custom authorization approach for WebApi

Tags: api, security, asp.net-web-api, authorization

I am going to implement Authorization for my Web API project. For that I have been reading various blogs, stack overflow answers about authorization in WebApi.

Two ways I saw recommended is either use Custom Authorization filter or use Web API Message Handler which gets executed before any filters.

I have very distinct requirement for my project.

1) I have third party authentication service implemented. Request will come to web API pipeline only when authenticated. I just need to perform authorization.

2) All actions in all my controllers are needs to authorize. (No anonymous access)

3) There are three levels of authorization I need to perform.

```
      a) Module Level (to see if user has access to said module)

      b) Record Level (if user has access to module see if he has access to particular resource accessing)

      c) Action Level (if user has access on both see if user can perform the said action [View/edit/delete/create]
```

4) All my url follow some predefined pattern {api/module/resource/resourceid} & action GET, POST, PUT, DELETE

My requirement is, I don't want to register any attribute over any of action or controller & I want to infer the all incoming request and authorize user based on it. (using delegate handler)

I am trying to use below approach :

1) from the incoming request url extract module name, resource name , resource id & User Id from cookies and pass this info to a function which will return true or based on some business rules.

Examples:

GET API - api/modulename1/resource1/id -> This URL will check VIEW access to modulename1,resource1 & resource id

POST API - api/modulename1/resource1 -> This URL will check CREATE access to modulename1,resource1

Same thing for delete & edit also.

I want to ask experts here a question if this approach will work or if there are any limitations with this approach.

Comment: This approach seems pretty good and I think that you are heading at the right direction here.

Comment: Thanks @DarinDimitrov Hopefully I will be able to generalize this for all my resources.